# C++ Calling a function with a vector as a parameter in main

Tags: c++, vector, parameter-passing

I have a myVector class:

```
class myVector {

public:

    void populateVector();
    void showMenu(vector <myVector> const &vec_first);

private:

    vector <myVector> &vec_first;

}
```

I haven't filled my vector yet but I want to essentially use the vector in the showMenu() function, however, a problem arises in my main when I attempt to call the showMenu() function.

```
int main() {
    myVector obj;
    obj.showMenu(vector <myVector> const &vec_first);
}
```

Codeblocks keeps saying:

> main.cpp|33|error: expected primary-expression before 'const'

Comment: You have a `vector<MyVector>` as a member of `myVector`? What? Could you use sensible type names please?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to declare a variable in the middle of a function argument list. This is not allowed.

Comment: Get a book or tutorial on C++

Comment: You are mixing up a lot of things. What do you wish to accomplish? What is the purpose of what you are doing??

Comment: sorry, meant `vector<myVector> vec_first`

Comment: "Codeblocks keeps saying ..." - Yes, and rightfully so, since what you gave the compiler is not valid C++ code.

Comment: Let me guess: you are trying do build a recursive menu/submenu structure?

Comment: Ok, then try to write this first into the question, meybe this can prevent it from being closed before you have your answer, use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38595002/edit) again. Ah, and don't forget the **title** as the most attractive/distracting part. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Your are confusing the function declaration with calling it. You need

```
int main() {
    myVector obj;
    vector<myVector> vec;
    obj.showMenu(vec);
}
```

or something like that

Comment: The types don't match up.

Comment: oops - fixed    ....

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't filled my vector yet but I want to essentially use the vector in the showMenu() function, however, a problem arises in my main when I attempt to call the showMenu() function.

Don't pass the vector (or anything) in through `showMenu`; it already has access to the vector, which is a member of the same class.

If you *did* want to pass a function argument, repeating the argument's original declaration would not be the way to do it. Only its name should be specified. Here that would be:

```
obj.showMenu(obj.vec_first);
```

… if `vec_first` weren't `private`.

It looks like you need to go back to basics and read the initial chapters of your C++ book.